# Intellij doesn't load repositories from SonaType repo

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea, repository, sonatype

for some reason I cant get Intellij to load repositories from Sonatype.
in settings->maven-> repositories
I do Add->insert the url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"->Ok

then I press the "Test" button - and I get the message "No repositories found".

I dont know what more information to give... please help.

Comment: IDEA expects Nexus or Artifactory URL, SonaType is already added by default: `http://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/`.

Comment: I see... but I need an artifact in a snapshot version...<br/>
that version is not in the service/local/ one...<br/>
what can I do?

Comment: Add `<repository>` containing this dependency in `pom.xml`.

Comment: Kind of old, but I had to change http to https to get depencendies to be pulled in from oss.sonatype.org - `https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/`